# How to auto-save a form on Android - Best practices

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-jetpack, android-mvvm, android-thread

[image: Sample app]

I am trying to introduce auto-save functionality on one of my Android applications. The idea is that as the user inputs first name, last name and after a fixed interval I would like to save that information to the server before the user hits **Next** button. The final goal is to have something similar to the draft option in the **Gmail** app where your email information is automatically saved. So, if there is a timer that runs every 10 seconds, I will pass the information on the screen to the ViewModel and let it deal with the logic of saving the data to the server.

A couple of options I have explored are.

1. Execute recurring code with a specified interval using Handler.
2. [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest) -- however this option has a minimum interval of 15 minutes which is a little too much for my use case.
3. [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) -- This option runs even if your application is not currently running, In my opinion, this option can be an overkill.

I wanted to know if there are best practices/blogs around this and if anyone I on the wrong path or potential red flags with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can make countdown for 10 second, when countdown is down save the data and call the countdown again.
when your activity is destroyed, so stop the countdown